# Loading .aspx page with AJAX as modal window

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to load a `.aspx` page as a modal window inside another `.aspx` page. But it seems it does not load the page correctly, i'm using **JQuery** `get()` method.
It's the code to load page and show it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.get('PagesForMenu.aspx', function (data) {
        modal.open({ content: data });
    });

});
```

It's the host page: http://pastebin.com/r3msLELP

The page I't trying to load has a [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) control and two **textboxs** and a button that **validates** controls (using **JQuery validate** plugin) then submits the form. 
When I run **PagesForMenu.aspx** from the browser it works fine (loads **CKeditor** and validating works). But when its loaded in modal window, **CKeditor** is not loaded and when I click the submit button it does not validate form.

**Page in the browser:**
[image: Page in the browser]

**Loaded page in the modal window:**
[image: Loaded page in the modal window]
The page i'm trying to load in modal window: http://pastebin.com/gS0JBBDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what's the problem. When you load a page with `get()`, it does not run scripts inside the page. you should put all scripts in a file and load it using  `$.getScript()`.